# Tensorflow batch normalization backward compatibility

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I am trying to train a semantic segmentation model using `tensorflow 1.15.4` but when i try to load the model into `tensorflow 1.5.0` using I get the following error:

`ValueError: No op named FusedBatchNormV3 in defined operations.`

What could be done to load the model in tensorflow with backward compatibility?

Comment: Sounds like Tensorflow version incompatibility, use the same Tensorflow version to load the model which was used while training. Between Tensorflow 1.15 and 1.5 many libraries were modified. It is better to use same version. Thanks!

Comment: Use Tensorflow 2.4.1 version, since it has library tf.raw_ops.FusedBatchNormV3 , check [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/raw_ops/FusedBatchNormV3)